# Find and replace using wild cards in a text file using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I've a text file in which i need to replace specific line items based on a search.

This is what i have in the file:

```
abc( xyz (124CKZ7859.pqr) craft(124CKZ7859.trm)
line1
line2
line3
abc( xyz (124CD7859.pqr) craft(124CD7859.pqr.trm)
line1
line2
line3
abc( xyz (128CKZ8559.pqr) craft(124CKZ7859.trm)
line1
line2
line3
```

What i need is to look for the 5th character (Z in this case) and delete the whole line and the lines under that till you get the next set

So the result should be

```
abc( xyz (124CD7859.pqr) craft(124CD7859.pqr.trm)
line1
line2
line3
```

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^abc\( xyz \(\w{5}Z.+\R(?:.+(?:\R|$)){3}`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : beginning of line
abc\( xyz \(    : literally
\w{5}           : 5 word character
Z               : letter Z
.+              : 1 or more any character but newline
\R              : any kind of linebreak
(?:             : start non capture group
  .+            : 1 or more any character but newline
  (?:\R|$)      : non capture group, linebreak or end of line (for the last line)
){3}            : must appear 3 times
```

**Result for given example:**

```
abc( xyz (124CD7859.pqr) craft(124CD7859.pqr.trm)
line1
line2
line3
```